# Instagram API get location data on geotagged photo

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible to retrieve location data about a business or a venue a photo was tagged at on `Instagram` using `python` and the `Instagram API`?

I have been using `access token` for my own account and have `Python Instagram` installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should query the image using the [`get_media`](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media) request to get its location details.

If the image was geo-tagged, the response will include the location details  like this:

```
"location":  {
    "latitude": 40.417044464,
    "name": "Puerta del Sol Madrid",
    "longitude": -3.703540741,
    "id": 3002373
}
```

To get this data with `python` use the [`Python-Instagram`](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram) package and call `api.media`:

```
import instagram

# Fill in access token here and image id
access_token = ''
media_id = ''
api = instagram.client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
res = api.media(media_id)
print res.location

# You should get a Location object with a latitude and a longitude point
>> Location: 3002373 (Point: (40.417044464, -3.703540741))
```